# kendo grid from json asp.net not work

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

This is my first time i follow kendo grid .I try to bind kendo grid using json but i always  return nothing .page code is

```
        <link href="Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.web.min.js"></script>


 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#grid").kendoGrid({
             dataSource: {
                 type: "json",
                 transport: {
                     read: function (options) {
                         $.ajax({
                             url: "kendogrid.aspx/GetUserList",
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function (result) {
                                 options.success(result);

                             },
                             pageSize: 10,
                             schema: {
                                 data: function (response) {
                                     return response.d;
                                 }
                             }
                         });
                     },
                     batch: true,
                     schema: {
                         type: 'json',
                         model: {
                             id: "U_ID",
                             fields: {
                                 U_ID: { type: "string" },
                                 U_UserName: { type: "string" },
                                 U_FullName: { type: "string" }
                             }
                         }
                     },
                     pageSize: 10
                 },
                 height: 430,
                 filterable: true,
                 groupable: true,
                 sortable: true,
                 pageable: true,
                 columns: [{
                     field: "U_ID",
                     title: "U_ID",
                     width: 140
                 }, {
                     field: "U_UserName",
                     title: "U_UserName",
                     width: 190
                 }, {
                     field: "U_FullName",
                     title: "U_FullName"
                 }]
             }
         });
     });


 </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


         <div id="grid">
        </div>


    </form>
```

and this my code behind

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetUserList()
    {
        string strConnString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["books_alaaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select * from Tbl_Users"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    var returnJSON = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          ClientUID = p.Field<string>("U_ID")
                                      }).ToList();
                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string json = serializer.Serialize(returnJSON);
                    return json;
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

its always return nothing where is the problem and how can i solve it??

Answer (score 0):

The response format should be like:

{"data":[ ... list of objects ...], "total": ... total number ...}